# C++ enum index value

Tags: c++, enums

As i understand if we have `enum n{sunday //0,monday //1 ,Tuesday //2}`

so `enum r { one, two = 4, three = 1, four};`

that the value of one should be  `0` , two is `4` , three is `1`  and four is `3`

i tried

`cout << four`

The result is

> 2

Comment: Yeah because `2` is after `1` which is `three`. Try `three = 3` and `four` will be `4`. The way I see it, you either assign values to all of them, or you don't assign at all. Otherwise, you can end up having duplicate values.

Comment: so `enum n{sunday //0,monday //1 ,Tuesday //2}` is right only if we didn't assign value to any element ?

Comment: Yes, if you don't change the flow, they get incremented by 1 on each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum` works like this, let's go with your example:

```
enum r { one, two = 4, three = 1, four};
```

`one` starts as `0` since no initial value is defined.

`two` is defined to be `4` if it wasn't declared as `4`, `two` would be `1` instead.

`three` is defined to be `1`, if it `two` and `three` wasn't declared earlier, it'd be `2` instead but it's `1`.

`four` doesn't have any equality, thus it will get the next value assigned, since `three` was 1, `four` will be `2`.

If no values were assigned, it'd look like this:

```
enum r { one, two, three, four};
```

`one` = `0`, `two` = `1`, `three` = `2`, `four` = `3`.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Since `three` is assigned to 1 and `four` is not, it's assigned as `three+1`, so `four = three + 1`